# Angular 2 - Email validation

Tags: angular

How can I check if email exists in database using custom validator? I have tried to found built in validator but there is none for that purpose.
I can't put code to question because I'm new to angular 2 and I don't know how to use custom validators.

In component I get all users from database and I need to check if email entered in input form already existis.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.registrationService.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.allUsers = data, error => this.errorMsg = error);
```

}

in service:

```
AddUser(regValues: any, allUsers: any) {
    if (regValues.email !== "" || regValues.password !== "" || regValues.nickname !== "" || regValues.confirmpassword !== "") {

        if (regValues.password != regValues.confirmpassword) {
            window.alert("Password and confirm password don't match. Please input same password in these two fields.");
        }
        else if (regValues.password.length < 7) {
            window.alert("Password must have minimum 7 characters. Please input password that has apropriate length.");
        }
        else if (regValues.username.length < 3) {
            window.alert("Nickname must have minimum 3 characters. Please input nickname that has apropriate length.");
        }
        else {

            if (allUsers.indexOf(regValues.email) !== -1) {
                window.alert("This email is already taken. Please choose another one.");
            }

            var regUser = {
                Email: regValues.email,
                PasswordHash: undefined,
                UserName: regValues.username
            }

            regUser.PasswordHash = Md5.hashStr(regValues.password);

            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            return this.http.post('/footballapi/user/add', regUser, options)
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                .catch(this.registrationService.errorHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

In component:

`Register(regValues: any) {
        let allUsers = this.registrationService.getUsers();
        this.registrationService.AddUser(regValues, allUsers).subscribe(data => this.allUsers = data, error => this.errorMsg = error);
    }`

HTML form:

```html
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<p>{{errorMsg}}</p>
<hr />
<form #registrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Register(registrationForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="email" ngModel required placeholder="Write your email address here..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Nickname:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="nickname" ngModel required placeholder="Write your nickname here..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="password" name="password" ngModel required placeholder="Write your password here..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" ngModel required placeholder="Write your password again..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registrationForm.form.valid">Confirm registration</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No one can help unless you share your code...

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. Angular is a client side framework, it is not related to database. If you want to check if an email exists in your database from the client, you must first send an HTTP request from your client to your server API, which will in turn send a request to your database. The database will return data, from there you can tell whether or not there is an existing email in your database because your database will have returned no line if it didn't find any matching email. Then the server can send a response back to your client.

Comment: So it's better to find matching email on backend and then send result to angular than to shuffle database data in angular?

Comment: Absolutely! You should (almost) always handle sensitive data server side. Emails, passwords, usernames, personal informations, etc. shouldn't be accessible to the user outside of their own information. In your code, it seems like you are fetching the information of all of your users to the client to use as validation to see if an email already exists. This is bad, do not do this. The user could easily access the list of email by simply typing "console.log(allUsers);" in his console terminal.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. So, after submiting form I need to make http.get request and send email through it, get answer from checkEmail method, if  response is true email is taken. right?

Comment: You send a request to your server using an HTTP Get with the email to validate as a parameter. On the server side, you make a request to the database using the email you received in parameter to see if there is any email that match. The database will either return a line to confirm that an email exists or no line to confirm that no email exists. With that information you can then send back a response to the client. You can use error codes with specific error messages in the response for clarity. error XX: email not found. I highly suggest to check some tutorial on whichever API you are using.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but I was stupid not to do it. Instead, I tried more complex and harder way to do the same thing -.-. I'm new to angular 2 and I will learn on my own mistakes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Async Validator

You have to write a Validator function, make a call to database and return a variable to say weather the email exists or not.

```
import {Control} from "@angular/common"
export class EmailValidators{
static checkEmail(control: Control){
  // make a db call{
// if exists
return {checkEmail : true}

}else return null;

}
}
```

Then this returned boolean flag will be passed as the aync validator parameter
if you use model driven forms and using formbuilder, include this in your component

```
export calss AppComponent{
constructor(fb : FormBuilder){
this.form = fb.group({
 email:['',Validators.EmailValidators.checkEmail]
})
}
}
```

Here is EmailValidators is the class that u import and checkEmail is the static method used to define your custom validation, which returns the boolean.

Comment: Unless you are using a database that can handle HTTP protocols, you cannot make a direct call to your database without going through a web server or another mean of handling HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First I need to create method on backend that has parameter 'email' and returns the boolean (for example) result to angular. If true, set validator to true.

Comment: @snaplemouton yes, I'm using web api project that has access to database using controller. In Angular I'm sending requests to controller and then controller goes to database and returns response to angular.

Comment: @user7479651 That's what you should have yes. Client <=> Server <=> Database. Client makes a request to Server for data, server handle the request and calls database for data, server validate the data and send back response to the client with proper error code if there is any.